# gdalwarp in a bash shell for loop

Tags: gdal

I would like mask several images in bash shell, `gdalwarp` works for me as a simple single line command:

```
gdalwarp -cutline mask.shp -cwhere 'kepnev="a.tif"' -crop_to_cutline a.tif a_masked.tif
```

..but it dosen't work with for loop:

```
for kep in *.tif;do
    gdalwarp -cutline mask.shp -cwhere 'kepnev="$kep"' -crop_to_cutline $kep ${kep/.tif}_masked.tif;done
```

Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the `$kep` variable in the `where` filter is wrapped in quotes. You need to wrap it again in single quotes:

```
gdalwarp -cutline mask.shp -cwhere 'kepnev="'$kep'"' -crop_to_cutline $kep ${kep/.tif}_masked.tif;done
```

When I run with `echo`, I get this output, which looks good to me:

```
gdalwarp -cutline mask.shp -cwhere kepnev="res_highpass.tif" -crop_to_cutline res_highpass.tif res_highpass_masked.tif
gdalwarp -cutline mask.shp -cwhere kepnev="res_highpass2.tif" -crop_to_cutline res_highpass2.tif res_highpass2_masked.tif
gdalwarp -cutline mask.shp -cwhere kepnev="res_highpass3.tif" -crop_to_cutline res_highpass3.tif res_highpass3_masked.tif
gdalwarp -cutline mask.shp -cwhere kepnev="sj00dsm.tif" -crop_to_cutline sj00dsm.tif sj00dsm_masked.tif
```

### Addendum

Actually, i got my quotes slightly wrong because you may need to wrap the entire `where` clause in single quotes. After a bit of educated guessing, I've come up with this:

```
gdalwarp -cutline mask.shp -cwhere "'"kepnev='"'$kep'"'"'" -crop_to_cutline $kep ${kep/.tif}_masked.tif;done
```

Which gives me this:

```
gdalwarp -cutline mask.shp -cwhere 'kepnev="sj00dsm.tif"' -crop_to_cutline sj00dsm.tif sj00dsm_masked.tif
```

Answer (score 4):

It is probably a quoting problem - when ever bash " & ' occur things get screwy. The best way to debug this sort of thing is to stick echo at the start of the gdalwarp line and see what the -cwhere 'kepnev="$kep"' bit looks like after a trip through the shell.

Remember that you can use intermediate variables in the for loop so may be something like

```
for kep in *.tif
  do
    wclause = kepnev="$kep"
    mask = ${kep/.tif}_masked.tif
    gdalwarp -cutline mask.shp -cwhere '$wclause' -crop_to_cutline $kep $mask
  done
```

might work better (as you can use echo to check each variable as you go.

Comment: There is not much screwy about this: Variables in double quotes `"` are expanded in Bash. Variables in single quotes `'` are **not** expanded. You can also escape single quotes with `\'`.