# Adding loop in gdal_translate

Tags: gdal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [gdalwarp in a bash shell for loop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24139/gdalwarp-in-a-bash-shell-for-loop)

I have several modis images (.hdf) from which I want to use only the one band (NDVI) and create a ".tif" image.
I have already finished all the preprocessing and I ended on the command below:

`gdal_translate -of GTiff $input documents/test.tif`

When I run it, I got the answer: "Too many command options"

BUT when I use the command "echo" and run the model by copy/pasting the result of the "echo" command:

`gdal_translate -of GTiff "HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"documents/modis_images/PullDir/0302579596islumc/MOD13Q1.A2011289.h19v04.005.2011307201911.hdf":MODIS_Grid_16DAY_250m_500m_VI:250m 16 days NDVI" documents/test.tif`

it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Do not worry, you only have a syntax problem, but not like the one in the possible duplicate. It works with `echo`, since it strips a layer of quotation marks, but when calling `gdal_translate`, it gets the raw contents of the variable. As a proof, if I `echo` your echoed result, all the quotation marks are gone:

```
$ echo "HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"documents/modis_images/PullDir/0302579596islumc/MOD13Q1.A2011289.h19v04.005.2011307201911.hdf":MODIS_Grid_16DAY_250m_500m_VI:250m 16 days NDVI"
HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:documents/modis_images/PullDir/0302579596islumc/MOD13Q1.A2011289.h19v04.005.2011307201911.hdf:MODIS_Grid_16DAY_250m_500m_VI:250m 16 days NDVI
```

Since we don't see the value of your input variable, it is hard to say where exactly the problem lies. The first thing you should do is quote input - `"$input"`, which will ensure there will be no word splitting (causing additional arguments to appear to gdal). If that's not enough, change how you construct `$input` and use a mix of single/double quotes and escape characters to make it robust (unlike the echoed line).