# How to use -where SQL in an ogr2ogr loop in GDAL/OGR (bash)?

Tags: shapefile, ogr

I'm using the following code:

```
while read line; do
for att in $line; do
ogr2ogr -where "newcode='$att'" -f "ESRI Shapefile" $OUTPUT/$att.shp $INDATA
done
done < $SCRIPT/newcodes.txt
```

The text file is being read correctly as shapefiles named after all names in the textfile list are being created. However, the shapefiles are empty (no attribute table or polygons). The ogr2ogr line of code works outside of the loop on a single feature within the shapefile. The newcodes.txt contains 3-5 letter codes e.g. aaa, gbe.

I think the problem is getting bash to treat $att as text to search for in the attribute table of the shapefile within the `-where` switch.

Any help much appreciated.

**Update:**

[image: Attribute Table Sample]

The shapefile has 15 columns in the table, and 6506 rows/features.

The 'newcode' field which I'am trying to read with the `-where` switch was joined to the table. I have tried using the loop with a pre-existing field and it still produced empty shapefiles.

**Update 2:**

After a bit more interrogation, I've noticed that the shapefiles are being produced with a space after their name. E.g. 'aaa .shp' rather than 'aaa.shp'. This probably means that the `$att` variable is being read with a space also, and therefore not matching anything in the attribute table. I have checked the text file, and there are no spaces in there. Still unsure how to fix.
[image]

e.g. 
cdg
cdh
cdi
cej
cea
eig
fjj
fja
fjf

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24139/gdalwarp-in-a-bash-shell-for-loop for a similar question and solution

Comment: Can you post the text file?

Comment: @iant modifying the loop as you've suggested in the link to something like this `wclause=newcode="$att"
ogr2ogr -where '$wclause' -f "ESRI Shapefile" $OUTPUT/$att.shp $INDATA` created a syntax error in the SQL statement.

Comment: You might want to put echo statements so we could see what the actual values of att are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my text file input for the script had a CTRL+M after each line. This is because I run Linux in a Virtual Machine and originally created the text file with codes in the Windows environment and didn't reformat.

The way I fixed this was to open the .txt file with a text editor and change the format to UNIX as opposed to Windows.

Thank you everyone for your help and sorry it was something as silly as this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to escaping the dollar sign.

```
ogr2ogr -where "newcode='\$att'" -f "ESRI Shapefile" $OUTPUT/$att.shp $INDATA
```

If that doesn't work you can try this

```
ogr2ogr -where 'newcode="$att"' -f "ESRI Shapefile" $OUTPUT/$att.shp $INDATA
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply. Even with the escape, the shapefiles are coming out empty, so the `-where` switch isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the second suggestion. Unfortunately, this produces the same empty shapefiles as a result too.

Comment: Can you show the structure of your shapefile's attribute table?

Comment: Have added some more to the question.