# Preparing CliMond data for Maxent

Tags: qgis, python, maxent

I had been working with BioClim data and that was working in Maxent. I could clip files and realign them etc.

Now I have some data from CliMond which is in two formats:

Either as text files

CM10_1975H_Bio01_V1.2.txt
CM10_1975H_Bio02_V1.2.txt
CM10_1975H_Bio03_V1.2.txt
etc

Or sets of data (lots of folders Bio1 to Bio40) as ESRI format files

/bio40$ ls

dblbnd.adf
hdr.adf
metadata.xml
prj.adf  sta.adf
w001001.adf
w001001x.adf

Is there a way that I can batch clip these to a format that is usable in Maxent (python or Qgis)?

Comment: are those text files ESRI ascii grids? can you post a few lines of one of them? If so, you have a lot of options for batch processing

Comment: ncols         2160
nrows         857
xllcorner     -180
yllcorner     -59.166666666667
cellsize      0.16666666666667
NODATA_value  -9999
-9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999

Comment: That was the text file. not the adf file!

Comment: if you are open to bash and gdal, check this discussion: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24139/gdalwarp-in-a-bash-shell-for-loop - I'm sure others will weigh in with python/QGIS options

Comment: and yes, those are ascii grids, which you can use directly in gdal (or gdal wrappers)